# How to perform column based replacement in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

df1

| Var | Val1 | Val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| var1 | 6 | 7 |
| var2 | 5 | -4 |
| var3 | -9 | 3 |
| var4 | 3 | -2 |

df2

| var | S1 | S2 | S3 | S4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| var1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| var2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| var3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| var4 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |

Expected outcome

df3

| var | S1 | S2 | S3 | S4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| var1 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 7 |
| var2 | 0 | 5 | -4 | 0 |
| var3 | -9 | 0 | -9 | 3 |
| var4 | 3 | 0 | -2 | 0 |

Dear Experts please help me to solve the query, where Val1 column values from df1 should be replaced when df2 column values are equal to 1 and Val2 column values should be replaced when df2 column values are equal to 2.

I am completely new to this please explain

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [np.select()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
import numpy as np
loop_cols=list(df2.columns)  #save original columns

df2=df2.merge(df1,how='left',left_on='var',right_on='Var') #merge on 'var'

def replace(col_name):
    return np.select([df2[col_name]==1,df2[col_name]==2],[df2['Val1'],df2['Val2']],default=df2[col_name])
    

for i in loop_cols[1:]: #apply function to needed columns. (S1,S2,S3,S4)
    df2[i]=replace(i)
    
df2=df2[loop_cols]
df2
    var     S1  S2   S3 S4
0   var1    6   0    0  7
1   var2    0   5   -4  0
2   var3    -9  0   -9  3
3   var4    3   0   -2  0
```

You can find the details of the function I use below.

```
def replace(col_name):
    condlist = [df2[col_name]==1,df2[col_name]==2] # --- > we have two contitions. İf equal 1 or equal 2

    choicelist = [df2['Val1'],df2['Val2']] # -- > if the conditions are met, what should be replaced with
    default = df2[col_name] # -- > if the conditions are not met keep original value

    return np.select(condlist, choicelist,default)
```